# Is there a way in HTML to set horizontal absolute positioning and vertical static positioning?

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, positioning

I have a variable number of "gadgets" in a site absolutely positioned in the viewport. I have them positioned with 'top' and 'left' properties. These gadgets are elements that can be arbitrarily added by users by dragging them from a little config panel to the viewport itself. The gadget absolute position is determined when the user drop the gadget. That position is saved in the database.

The problem appeared when I tried to generate a print layout and expand the gadgets vertically . In fact I want to do this because most of the gadgets are tables (jqGrids), and I want them to show more rows in the printable mode than in the normal screen mode. So the problem is that when I expand the grids vertically they may overlap (almost always they will overlap).

The desired result will be the one in the tittle, keep the left position absolute and the top static. I don't know any straightforward solution to this issue, is there any?

Here is a possible arrangement (when gadget1 and 2 are expanded they will overlap gadget3)

```
    +---------+
    |         |       +--------------------------------+
    |    1    |       |                                |
    +---------+       |                2               |
                      +--------------------------------+

            +------------------+
            |        3         |
            +------------------+
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please describe how they should look on the print out? Obviously they should have more rows, but how should they be positioned?

Answer (score 1):

Override `position: absolute` with `position: static` in your print stylesheet and use `margin-left: Npx` instead of `left: Npx` for horizontal positioning.

Comment: Mm, I will try this aproach. I don't know if it'll work in the following case. Suppose I have 3 gadgets absolutely positioned in this order:

Comment: Mm, I will try this aproach. I don't know if it'll work in the following case. Suppose I have 3 gadgets absolutely positioned in this order: <div style="position:absolute;top:1000px;"/> ... <div style="position:absolute;top:500px;"/> ... <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;"/>. So the first div in the html is the bottommost renderized one, the second is in the middle and the last one is the first one! And this is not an hypothetical case, this is actually happening in my code, I think I should order the divs by top position, maybe?

Comment: Yes, you can sort the widgets by their top position when generating HTML / adding new widgets dynamically, it will look the same as before on screen, and it will also work for print.